# Unable to create Excel Sheet at runtime

Tags: java, excel, selenium, poi-hssf

I am trying to create an excel sheet at runtime using selenium. I am using following code but after running program when i open the excel file there is no newly created sheet in it.i am unable to understand why is it not created as it does not show any Exception/Error and also it is showing an Object reference which shows that the sheet should be created.

```
public void createSheet() 
  {
      try
      {
         FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream("registration_data.xls");
         work=new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
         System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
      }
      for(int i=1;i<rownum;i++)
        {
          HSSFSheet sheet1=work.createSheet("dd"+i);
          System.out.println("Sheet ref: "+sheet1);
        }
  }
```

Comment: You don't appear to be writing out the file once you're done, could that be it?

Comment: yea that was the problem.. i had not written out file..Thanks for the help.:)